# Flexbox column reverse en @media

Tags: html, css3, flexbox

estoy usando flexbox y en un @media no me toma flex-direction: column reverse.

```css
.reverse {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

#fila-servicios {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 /*flex-direction: column; HICE ESTO Y IGUAL NO FUNCIONA*/
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}
.titulo-diseño {
 display: block;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 padding: 70px 0px 0px 0px;
 color: white;
 background-color: #47AB6C;
 text-align: left;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
.titulo-diseño i {
 font-size: 17px;
}
.contenido-diseño {
 display: block;
 width: 300px;
 text-align: left;
}
.titulo-estilo {
 display: block;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 padding: 70px 0px 0px 0px;
 color: white;
 background-color: #47AB6C;
 text-align: right;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
.titulo-estilo i {
 font-size: 17px;
}
.contenido-estilo {
 display: block;
 width: 300px;
 text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="fila-servicios" class="reverse">
   <div class="titulo-estilo">
    <i class="fas fa-palette"></i>
    <h1>Estilo</h1>
   </div>
<div class="contenido-estilo">
    <p>LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</p>
   </div>   
  </div>
<div id="fila-servicios" class="reverse">
   <div class="contenido-diseño">
    <p>LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem</p>
   </div>
   <div class="titulo-diseño">
    <i class="fas fa-palette"></i>
    <h1>Diseño</h1>
   </div>   
  </div>
```

Comment: cual es el comportamiento esperado  y cual es el fallo que estas obteniendo, tu pregunta es poco clara

Comment: En la pagina sin @media los titulos van a la izquierda o a la derecha pero cuando lo hago responsivo quiero que aparezcan en columna y no un titulo texto texto titulo...; quiero que aparezca titulo texto titulo texto...

Comment: Aqui está funcionando correctamente, deberías hacer un [mcve] donde podamos ver el problema

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, dos elementos no pueden compartir el mismo ID.

A parte, en el HTML tienes un encabezado arriba y otro abajo, por lo que `flex-direction: column-reverse` siempre los va a enfrentar.

Corrige eso y luego usa el selector `:nth-child(odd)` o `:nth-child(even)` para aplicarle tus propiedades flex en el breakpoint que quieras invertir el orden.

Puedes hacerlo de dos formas: con `flex-direction: column-reverse` o aplicando la propiedad `order: 2` al título.

```css
    article {
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
    }
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    article:nth-child(odd) {
       flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
</article>
<article>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
</article>
```

Ejecuta el snippet y luego ponlo en pantalla completa para ver la diferencia.